# Facebook chat code doesn't pass html5 validator

Tags: html, facebook-javascript-sdk

The facebook chat widget requires use of code such as

`<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="123456789000"></div>`

But that unsurprisingly throws an error at https://validator.w3.org/nu/:

> Error: Attribute page_id not allowed on element div at this point.

Why didn't they just go with the spec and use `data-page_id` instead?

I know HTML validation isn't the be-all and end-all, but is there a simple trick to fix this, it wreaks havoc with my OCD.

Answer (score -1):

The error is caused by page_id. Div do not have that attribute.

But you can add it using Angular:

`let fbDiv = document.createElement('div');`

`fbDiv.setAttribute('page_id', page_id);`

`document.body.appendChild(fbDiv);`

Then use FB.XFBML.parse:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

I hope this helps.